# some files do not show up in explorer when mounted via MTP

Tags: files, mtp, hidden

I have a **moto G 5** (reteu, NPPS25.137-72-4) updated to android 7.0

I have a **SD card** formatted as **internal** *memory/storage* inside the phone.

When I mount the phone as *MTP* on my PC, some files do not show up in the file explorer.

Specifically these files are `wigleWifi` directory created by *wigle* app, and `ssidLogger.log` created by *ssidLogger* app (not available on Play Store)

This is happening on *ubuntu 17.10* or *Windows 10 1709*. So there is some consistency here in the bug, indicating it might come from the phone ?

I checked the permissions on the files/directory from a terminal android emulator and they have the same permissions as the other files that do show up, like rw-rw---- root.everybody ...

*Note*: those files have been written after I have attached and formatted my SD card as internal storage. Those files are visible in Solid Explorer on the phone or in the built-in explorer from Settings/Storage.

If I create a test file in Jota editor, it shows up instantly when saved in the file exporer, for example.

Why do those file not show up in a file explorer on a PC ? and how do I make them show up ?

Comment: Change the name of the file and see if it shows up

Comment: So I guess this a crappy phone. I heard about possible corruption of the SD card when shutting down the phone for this model. And this did not even happen here but all my files are gone. The card has been reformated without asking me about it !!! f***. siiiight.

Comment: Might be rather a combination. You write you're using Windows 10 and MTP? Wasn't there a serious bug in the way Win10 deals with MTP, causing massive data loss? See e.g. [here](https://borncity.com/win/2017/08/30/windows-10-has-an-mtp-problem-with-android-devices/). I cannot tell if that bug was solved as I neither use Windows nor MTP. To me, both are too unreliable.